# Query to show average # of months all accounts with specific role have been active

Tags: php, wp-query, users, statistics, account

I'm trying to determine how long (in average number of months) all accounts (active & deactivated accounts) under role "x" have been around in my site.

I have the following piece of code however don't know how to query further:

```
<?php
$result = count_users();
echo 'There are ', $result['total_users'], ' total users';
foreach($result['avail_roles'] as $role => $count)
    echo ', ', $count, ' are ', $role, 's';
echo '.';
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Note that you don't join up strings together in PHP using commas, the code in your question is not valid PHP and will cause syntax errors. Please look up basic PHP syntax. Additionally, where is this file located and what is it called?

Comment: The code is from wordpress.org codex site.  The code would echo the text out on a page on the site. I have installed a plugin to allow for php to be used in posts.

Comment: You can't use WP functions in the PHP for those plugins, and those plugins are an extreme security risk. I cannot understate how dangerous plugins that let you put PHP into posts are. Eitherway the PHP for those plugins has to be self contained, you can't use the code snippets from the codex with them. Use shortcodes instead if you want to run PHP code and embed the result inside a post. Again, plugins that let you put PHP inside post content are incredibly dangerous, and one of the most dangerous things you can do to a site